# How do I access a view from within a tab controller?

Tags: ios, ios5, delegates, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

```
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"dischargeSegue"])
{
    UITabBarController *dc = [segue destinationViewController];

    dischargeView *discharge = (dischargeView *)[[dc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0];
    discharge.delegate = self;
}
```

I'm trying to set the delegate for the initial view of a tab view controller.  This is what I was trying, but get the following error:  unrecognized selector sent to instance

[image]

Comment: (dischargeView *)[[dc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] view];   Try using this

Comment: That doesn't error out, but it's not right either.  My delegate methods aren't getting called.

Comment: dischargeView is a view or view controller?

Comment: Controller, the tab bar controller has two views, the first one is inside a navigation controller, so I thought I needed to get the first tab bar, then get the actual controller within that view controller.

Comment: might be then you need something like - (dischargeView *)[[[dc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] viewControllers ] objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: have you checked with above suggested code, earlier it was crashing as you are accessing navigation controller?

Comment: That last one was it, if you post it I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -

```
dischargeView *discharge =  (dischargeView *)[[[dc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```